# How to write a vector of objects into a file?

Tags: c++, vector

I coded an application to register travel reservations. I would like to write the information of the reservations into files. One for train and another for plane travels. I have decided to put for example, the train reservation inside a vector, and I would like to write the content of that vector into a text file. I am still going to add other objects into that vector. The problem is that I have not found a way to write the content of the vector into the file. I have tried the way below, I got it from an example, but I guess it does not fit to my case, since it did not work. Could you help me with that?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Data.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Reservation.h"
#include "FlightReservation.h"
#include "TrainReservation.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Data data(1,1,2020);
    Person person("George", "Man");
    TrainReservation train(data, person, "common", 100, 50);

    Data data2(1,6,2020);
    Person person2("Ana", "Woman");
    FlightReservation flight(data2, person2, "ABC1180", "50A");

    cout<<"Data:\n"<<train.data<<endl;
    cout<<"Customer:\n"<<train.getCustomer()<<endl;
    cout<<"Train: "<<train.getTrain()<<", vagon: "<<train.getVagon()<<", seat: "<<train.getSeat()<<endl;

    cout<<"Data:\n"<<flight.data<<endl;
    cout<<"Customer:\n"<<flight.getCustomer()<<endl;
    cout<<"Flight: "<<flight.getFlight()<<", seat: "<<flight.getSeat()<<endl;

vector<TrainReservation> v;
v.push_back(train);

fstream f("test.txt", ios::out);
for(vector<FlightReservation>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end() ; ++i)
{

f.write((char *)&(*i),sizeof(*i));

}
f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is generally highly inadvisable to output an instance of a C++ class using binary I/O (`f.write()`) particularly if the class or any of it members has virtual functions.   Look up the notion of POD types (or "standard layout" types in recent C++ standards) for more information about types that are safe for performing binary I/O.    Also, by default, a `fstream` is not opened in binary mode, and the effect of using binary I/O to a non-binary stream is undefined.

Comment: Look into serialization.

Comment: Don't try to use code you don't understand. There is no way you can make any sense out of it. If you want to encode a vector as a stream of bytes (which is what a file is), then decide on a form of encoding to use and write code to convert to and from that form of encoding.